# how to add "alt" for all image in wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, images, tags

I am new to wordpress and StackExchange. I need to add alt attribute to all existing images for screen readers. But I have no idea which php file I need to work on.

Also, how does wordpress make pics? which php file do this job? Thanks!

Comment: You can add alt tags to all images in the image library. Read this post - https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/image-alt-tags-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem here but if you want to check all the images on your wordpress you need to go on your dashboard > media.

You can also find all your images on your FTP under the file:

wp-includes/upload

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. I mean I need to make some php code change in there, not only work in the dashboard. But I don't know in which php file I could manage all images.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to add 'alt attributes' to all images one by one in the WordPress Dasboard. Yes, if you want to add different alt attribute to different image then you need to do it one by one. To do this follow the steps given below

1. Login to WordPress Dashboard
2. Go to Media from Left Navigational Menu
3. Select the Particular Image or Media you want to add alt attributes
4. Add Alt Attributes and Click 'Ok' to save it.

That's it. In this way you need to edit each and every existing image uploaded on your wordpress site.